# object[] to int //from database

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to get my database data into a particular variable,
my database handling class. And I am trying to store data in the current form class:

```
var list = x.Rows();
if (list.Count != 0)
{
  Object[] ar = new Object[1];
  //Object[] ar = list[0];
  list.CopyTo(ar, 0);
  var quntity1 = (int) ar[1];
}
```

and row method

```
public List<Object> Rows()
{
  List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
  Cn.Open();
  Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (Dr.Read())
  {
    Object[] array = new Object[Dr.FieldCount];
    Dr.GetValues(array);
    list.Add(array);
  }
  return list;
}
```

In my table total 3 Columns and I m trying to get 2nd column

Comment: Indenting your code would help readability.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: why not store integers as integers?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your declarations, so we must infer types, and you haven't asked a question at all. I see about half a dozen design issues. Your question and code need a lot of work. However, I'm going to guess you're using a SqlDataReader. I generally use the methods in System.Convert to cast from object.

Comment: i think you have to use AddRange method!

Comment: @VDN: no, he wants to store a complete recordset in one `object[]`. If you'd use `AddRange` you'd flatten all fields into a single list and you don't know anymore which field belongs to which record. But he should use a `List<ClassName>` where the type `ClassName` contains all properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it my answer
just replace row method's return type with object array and create list object[] inserted of list object.

```
var list = x.Rows();
if (list.Count != 0)
{
    Object[] ar = list[0];
    var quntity1 = (int) ar[1];
}
```

and row method

```
public List<Object[]> Rows()
    {
        List<Object[]> list = new List<Object[]>();
        Cn.Open();
        Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Dr.Read())
        {
            Object[] array = new Object[Dr.FieldCount];
            Dr.GetValues(array);
            list.Add(array);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

its work for me. thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more along these lines, rather than casting later on when you need to use the value.

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

static class DataAccess
{
    public static MyObject GetMyObject(int id, string conString)
    {
        var cmd = GetCommandById(id);
        cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        using (cmd.Connection)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var n = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
                var v = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Value"]);
                return new MyObject()
                {
                    Name = n, 
                    ID = id, 
                    Value = v
                };
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    static SqlCommand GetCommandById(int id)
    {
        var q = @"
            SELECT * FROM TABLE.MYOBJECT obj WHERE obj.ID = @id";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(q);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        return cmd;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am newbie in programming. Thank you for your comments. Michael i m use global class for database its work on all table that's why not require to declare specific table column. thank you for your code ill try it.